# Excel Interop C#: I want to select a range of cells with colored background as ExcelRange

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I want to select a range of cells Using Excel Interop C# in which background color is "LightBlue".? How do I do that.

Comment: I dont know how to try,. but just know i have to us Range. Autofilter() method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet;
    int endColumn = 16384;
    int endRow = 65536;
    var results= new List<Excel.Range>();
    for(var i=0;i<=endColumn;i++)
    {
       for(var j=0;j<=endRow;j++)
       {  
          if(worksheet.Cells[j,i].Interior.Color ==   System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LightBlue))
         {
          result.Add(worksheet.Cells[j,i]);
         }
       }
     }
```

Comment: is it possible to avoid List<Range>  or convert the List<Range> to a Range

Comment: I dont know exactly your requirement, so I just assumed you will have a lot of different LightBlue range. you can create smaller function and using it as recursive... but you might not have a performance..

Comment: I have a lot of LightBlue range. But If a Row is Blue it is completely Blue. I dont need to loop through all the cells.

Comment: oh.. so it would be easier for you right?  do you need me to correct my source code for you?

Comment: I have done that. The thing is Looping through the Rows delays the running of application. I'm Looking for a way to select or filter the blue cells to a range. without looping.